# Question about Self Joins. Seeing if two users interacted

Tags: mysql, sql

I was given a SQL assignment that is the following table simulating a dating app: Table name = dating

```
user_id | viewing_profile_id | date | liked
   1              2             x       yes
   1              3             x       yes
   2              1             x       yes
   2              3             x       no
   3              1             x       no
   3              2             x       no
```

essentially I want to see the % of profiles that match each other. a match is when both profiles like each other.

I think I know what I have to do. Perform a Self join onto the table itself and use a case when for when the profiles like each other.

```
select t.date, sum(t.match) / count(t.match) as p_match
from (
select s1.user_id, s1.viewing_profile_id, 
date_trunc('day',s1.date) as date, case when s1.liked = 'yes' 
and s2.liked = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end as match
from dating s1
left join dating s2 on s2.ser_id = s1.viewing_profile_id
group by 1,2) t
group by 1
```

Since this is just a made up table, and I do not have any data execute this on, I was wondering if I can get some insight into whether or not this would work.

I am expecting the subquery to produce something like the following:

```
user_id | viewing_profile_id | date | match
   1              2             x       1
   1              3             x       0
   2              1             x       1
   2              3             x       0
   3              1             x       0
   3              2             x       0
```

Comment: With that sample table data, what's the expected result?

Comment: @jarlh thank you for responding. I would prefer Mysql but it is open-ended.  I also added the expected results.

Comment: The expected result's columns don't match the query's select list.

Comment: The expected query was for the subquery, not the main query. My logic for the main query is just to sum the new match column for total matches, and count the total to get a % on matched profiles. It's the subquery I need help with. Specifically with the case and self join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to left self join the table on the conditions you have:

```
select 
  d1.*,
  case when d2.user_id is null then 0 else 1 end `match`
from dating d1 left join dating d2
on 
  d1.user_id = d2.viewing_profile_id 
  and d1.viewing_profile_id = d2.user_id
  and d1.liked = 'yes' and d2.liked = 'yes'
order by d1.user_id, d1.viewing_profile_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jSsPwbNDhLbxTgAGzC3CNm/0).
Results:

```
| user_id | viewing_profile_id | date | liked | match |
| ------- | ------------------ | ---- | ----- | ----- |
| 1       | 2                  |      | yes   | 1     |
| 1       | 3                  |      | yes   | 0     |
| 2       | 1                  |      | yes   | 1     |
| 2       | 3                  |      | no    | 0     |
| 3       | 1                  |      | no    | 0     |
| 3       | 2                  |      | no    | 0     |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* for matched users*/
SELECT *
FROM user viewed, user viewing
WHERE viewed.user_id = viewing.viewing_profile_id
and viewed.liked='yes'
and viewing.liked='yes'


/* for Match_Percentage */
SELECT 
(SELECT count(*)
FROM user viewed, user viewing
WHERE viewed.user_id = viewing.viewing_profile_id 
and viewed.liked='yes'
and viewing.liked='yes')
/
(SELECT count(*) FROM user)
*100 as Match_Percentage
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a flag specifying whether the reverse matches, then:

```
select d.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from dating d2
                where d2.user_id = d.viewing_profile_id and
                      d2.viewing_profile_id = d.user_id and
                      d2.liked = 'yes'
               ) and
        d.liked = 'yes'
       ) as match
from dating d;
```